# How can I give Page flip effect in `UIScrollview`?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am working on an application in which I am using `UIScrollview`, in that I need to use page flip effect.

How can I give Page flip effect in `UIScrollview`?

**Note**:  In UIScrollview when we change Page at that time Scrolling the Page forward & backward. Can it be possible to give Page scroll effect at the time when we scroll page?

Comment: Please explain your question better. Page flip is effect is available natively from iOS 5 only with PageViewController. UIScrollView is not the way to do that any way.

Comment: In UIScrollview when we change Page at that time Scrolling the Page forward & backward. can it be possible to give Page scroll effect at the time when we scroll page.

Comment: use - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;  method and perform animation in thsi method. Make sure that Paging s enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forward flip -

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0f];
animation.startProgress = 0;
animation.endProgress   = 1;
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
animation.type = @"pageCurl";
animation.subtype=@"fromRight";
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
[lyr addAnimation:animation forKey:@"WebPageCurl"];
```

Backward flip -

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.5f];
animation.startProgress = 0;
animation.endProgress   = 1;
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
animation.subtype=@"fromRight";
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;

[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
[lyr addAnimation:animation forKey:@"WebPageCurl"];
```

you can use this code when UIScrollView delegates.